# How do i grant remote access to one particular mysql table?

Tags: mysql, remote-access

A client wants access from there ip address to a specific mysql table for their CRM program. I am developing the website part and collect data with a form.

Which steps should i make to grant access to a particular mysql table from one ip address and how can i test it?

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* to jsmith@'69.234.27.102' IDENTIFIED BY 'jimspassword';
```

can i replace * with the specific table? And how do i test this from my pc?

regards,

Comment: Why don't you just go ahead and check it? Yes, you can replace * with the table name. And you can test it with: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.mytable to yourtestuser@'your_ip_address' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';`

Comment: @Mike i tried and it looks like the user+pwd+ip is added but when testing i get 
`
[root@server1 mydomain.com]# mysql -u yourtestuser -p -h x3.xxx.xx3.156
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x3.xxx.xx3.156' (113)`

Comment: @mike when not using -h x3.xxx.xx3.156 i do get the ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'yourtestuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) as expected. But with the -h ip-address i don't get access

Comment: oh and i can see the user is created by `mysql> select * from mysql.user where User = 'yourtestuser';`

Comment: Check if your MySQL is listening (`netstat -ln`). If not, make sure you have `port = 3306` and NO `skip-networking` in your `my.cnf` file. Optionally you can make it listening only on particular interfaces with `bind-address`.

Comment: @mike really appreciate your input.  I guess MySQL isn't listening as the output doesn't read mysql, but i do see tcp 0  0.0.0.0:3306.
Can i try another port? how should it look if MySQL is listening?

BTW: when i try to login with user/pwd combo created with phpmyadmin i can access mysql, but this isn't specified with a particular ip.

Comment: You can do `netstat -lnp` to see the name of the process which is listening. But if you read `0 0.0.0.0:3306` it is probably MySQL listening on this socket. What about the firewall: `iptables-save`? Can you telnet to this port from your pc (telnet mysql_box_ip 3306)?

Comment: cat my.cnf -> and i don't see any port or skip-networking configuration

Comment: everything is ACCEPT so no firewall problem i guess
i can't use telnet, it doesn't work.

Comment: i am also trying to create a db user with plesk with just a table access, leaving the ip address part for now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28060/discussion-between-mike-and-alex)

Answer (score 2):

Grant privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.mytable to yourtestuser@'your_ip_address' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
```

Remember to:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

after that.

Make MySQL listening for network connections:

In `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
```

Check with:

```
netstat -lnp
```

Make sure firewall does not block your connections

```
iptables-save
```

Check if everything is OK on network level from your PC with:

```
telnet mysqlbox_ip 3306
```

Make sure if there is a user defined in MySQL:

```
mysql> \u mysql
mysql> select * from user;
```

Make sure there are table privileges defined:

```
mysql> select * from tables_priv;
```

Comment: really really appreciate it. I have followed all your steps above, and i got all the output i would expect, even the last one: i see the users created with Host, db, table etc. 
Host in this case should be the remote ip where i like to make the connection from, right?

Comment: btw telnet outputs
Connected to mysqlbox_ip.
Escape character is '^]'.
J
3w~4'c?O!S`js$RU3=vmysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.
is this correct?

Comment: In Ubuntu I use netstat -tln